# git automatic merge of two commits applying the same change

Tags: git, merge

Does an automatic merge in git recognize when two different commits made the same changes to a file? Or does this result in a conflict?

Comment: so the answer would be a simple "no", right?

Comment: Pretty much, but then the obvious follow-up question is "can I make it behave that way?" Please accept the nominated duplicate.